# How to apply lgamma to a matrix using Rcpp (and will it be faster)?

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, rcpp

I am wondering if I can apply lgamma on all entries of a large matrix using Rcpp.  I tried using a vector:

```
// lgammaRcpp.cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector lgammaRcpp(NumericVector v){
    NumericVector out;
    out = lgamma(v);
    return(out);
}
```

I did a simple microbenchmarking:

```
library("microbenchmark")
x <- round(runif(100000)+50000);
microbenchmark(
   lgammaRcpp(x),
   lgamma(x)
)
```

and the Rcpp is slightly faster:

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 lgammaRcpp(x) 5.405556 5.416283 5.810254 5.436139 5.511993 8.650419   100    
     lgamma(x) 5.613717 5.628769 6.114942 5.644215 6.872677 9.947497   100
```

When I try using a "NumericMatrix", however:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix lgammaRcpp(NumericMatrix v){
    NumericMatrix out;
    out = lgamma(v);
    return(out);
}
```

there are errors that I don't understand, e.g.

```
/home/canghel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector   /Matrix.h:83:13: note: Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>& Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::operator=(const Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>&) [with int RTYPE = 14; StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
 Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other) {
```

My questions are: 1) Is there a way to modify my function to apply lgamma over all entries to a matrix?  and 2) Is it worth it, or is the underlying library that is called for the lgamma function the same for C++ and R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Rcpp Sugar* tends to return Vectors unless otherwise specified. Thus, you will *always* get back in this case a `Vector` of type `Numeric` e.g. `NumericVector`. See my notes on different sugar functions here: https://github.com/coatless/rcpp-api

The following allows for a compilation under the above note:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector lgammaRcpp(NumericMatrix v) { 
    NumericVector out;
    out = lgamma(v);
    return(out);
}
```

2. It is highly unlikely you will see a large speed up as the functions being used are the same. This is partially indicated with your above benchmarks and can be verified by looking at [Rcpp Math defines](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/math.h#L45). **Now, this isn't to say a benefit is not available.** In particular, the main benefit here is if you are encapsulating a routine completely in C++. In which case, your routine will be significantly quicker if you use Sugar functions if compared to calling an *R* function from *C++*.

Comment: I am still a bit confused on 1) -- it there any way to specify to get back a matrix?  In Dirk's answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950880/rcpp-syntactic-sugar-for-produces-unexpected-results-when-dealing-with-numeri?rq=1) you can multiply a matrix by a scalar.  Is there no option to apply lgamma to every entry of a matrix (except with a for loop over rows or something like that)?  i.e. Is the answer that lgamma _always_ expects a vector?

Comment: `lgamma` is a function that always _returns_ a vector. However, it can accept a matrix. Basically, _Rcpp_ simplifies the structure from that of a Matrix to a Vector in this calculation. Regarding the multiplication by a constant, that is another bit all together. Generally speaking, matrices in Rcpp have limited operational support. If you need matrix operations indepth its best to use RcppArmadillo or RcppEigen.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you! This worked: 
    ```// [[Rcpp::export]]
    NumericVector lgammaRcpp(NumericMatrix v){
        NumericVector out;
        out = lgamma(v);
        return(out);
     }```
Now I'll just look up how to change out back to matrix... or use RccpArmadillo. :)

Comment: Yup, thank you for the RcppArmadillo suggestion, this worked nicely:
```#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat lgammaRcppArma(arma::mat m) {
arma::mat out = lgamma(m);
return(out);
}```

Answer (score 3):

It seems better (i.e. faster) to apply functions like lgamma/digamma to a matrix using the `Rfast` package.

```
library("microbenchmark");
library("RcppArmadillo");
library("Rfast");
sourceCpp("lgammaRcpp.cpp");

x <- matrix(round(runif(100000)+50000), 100, 1000);
microbenchmark(
    lgammaRcpp(x),
    lgamma(x),
    Rfast::Lgamma(x)
)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
lgammaRcppArma(x) 4.654526 4.919831 5.577843 5.413790 5.888895 9.258325   100
lgamma(x) 5.572671 5.840268 6.582007 6.131651 7.280895 8.779301   100
Rfast::Lgamma(x) 4.450824 4.588596 5.128323 4.791287 5.608678 6.865331   100
```

where I had:

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat lgammaRcpp(arma::mat m) {
    arma::mat out = lgamma(m);
    return(out);
}
```