# Matrix Multiplication of List Components in RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, list, rcpp, matrix-multiplication

I want to create a function in RcppArmadillo, which takes as input two Lists a and b, and then returns a List "out" which contains as components the matrix product of the corresponding components of a and b: out(i) = a(i)*b(i) (in a for loop). That is I know beforehand that all the components of Lists a and b will be matrices.

This can be achieved in RcppArmadillo with the use of `as<arma::mat>` like in the following code example:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

List test_1(List a, List b){
List out(a.size());
  for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
   out(i) = as<arma::mat>(a(i))*as<arma::mat>(b(i));
  }
  return out;
}
```

However, because this is intented to be used as part of an MCMC algorithm with the goal to make it faster and because I also took a look to this post:
[Index element from list in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973442/index-element-from-list-in-rcpp/18014655)

I was wandering whether using such a user-specified class as `ListOf<arma::mat>` for example, would result in faster computations when compared to the above code. I tried to benchmark it, using the ListOf class template given by Romain Francois in the link.  However, I could not make it work getting the error "*reference to 'ListOf' is ambiguous*" when tried to source the code. Moreover, I tried to source the whole code of Romain Francois, in the link above, and still got the same error. Therefore, despite the fact that I am not experienced in creating my own class templates as I am kind of new in Rcpp and C++, I could not make it to compare the two solutions in terms of speed.

Nevertheless, to summarize a little bit, my main questions are:

1. Is the custom class template solution (In other words creating a new class where you specify a priori the class of the List components) the only alternative to `as<class>` in order to achieve matrix multiplication of List components in RcppArmadillo?
2. If indeed it is the only alternative, would it be faster than using `as<class>`?

Answer (score 0):

You may be overcomplicating this.  From R, you get `SEXP`  which you instantiate cheaply -- see the set of benchmarks [in the RcppArmadillo package](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/examples/fastLm.r).

And in general, profiling beats conjecture.  Just try different things and measure them...